# connect custom tableviewcell to Uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am new in programming so I really need ur help. Basically I have very basic table view controller with custom cell inside.

```
import UIKit

class RestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var restaurantNames = ["Cafe Deadend", "Homei", "Teakha", "Cafe Loisl", "Petite Oyster", "For Kee Restaurant", "Po's Atelier", "Bourke Street Bakery", "Haigh's Chocolate", "Palomino Espresso", "Upstate", "Traif", "Graham Avenue Meats", "Waffle & Wolf", "Five Leaves", "Cafe Lore", "Confessional", "Barrafina", "Donostia", "Royal Oak", "Thai Cafe"]

var restaurantImages = ["cafedeadend.jpg", "homei.jpg", "teakha.jpg", "cafeloisl.jpg", "petiteoyster.jpg", "forkeerestaurant.jpg", "posatelier.jpg", "bourkestreetbakery.jpg", "haighschocolate.jpg", "palominoespresso.jpg", "upstate.jpg", "traif.jpg", "grahamavenuemeats.jpg", "wafflewolf.jpg", "fiveleaves.jpg", "cafelore.jpg", "confessional.jpg", "barrafina.jpg", "donostia.jpg", "royaloak.jpg", "thaicafe.jpg"]

var restaurantLocations = ["Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "London", "London", "London", "London"]

var restaurantTypes = ["Coffee & Tea Shop", "Cafe", "Tea House", "Austrian / Causual Drink", "French", "Bakery", "Bakery", "Chocolate", "Cafe", "American / Seafood", "American", "American", "Breakfast & Brunch", "Coffee & Tea", "Coffee & Tea", "Latin American", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "British", "Thai"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return restaurantNames.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RestaurantTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.nameLabel.text = restaurantNames[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImages[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
    cell.locationLabel.text = restaurantLocations[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.typeLabel.text = restaurantTypes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]


    return cell
```

Also i have 4 sep table view controllers. My question is how can I establish segues so when I press for example the first cell - "a" tableviewcontroller opened. When I pressed second cell -"b"tableviewcontroller opened.

I am very very new in programming, so please guys,write everything step by step.
Thank you so much for the HELP!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other responses are developed for Swift2 but you want it for Swift3 that's why you can't find the methods.

So I am going to provide you a very basic example of navigation between TableViewControllers hopefully it can help you to understand how the navigation works so that you implement it in your project.

## Result

[image]

## Code

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
  }
  
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Go to Table \(indexPath.row + 1)"
    return cell
  }
  
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let numberOfRow = indexPath.row
    
    switch numberOfRow{
    case 0:
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "showA", sender: numberOfRow)
    case 1:
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "showB", sender: numberOfRow)
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
  
  // This method will be useful to you
  // in case you want to send any info
  // to your destination view controllers.
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showA" {
      let tableViewControllerA = segue.destination as! TableViewControllerA
      tableViewControllerA.someData = sender as? Int
    } else if segue.identifier == "showB" {
      let tableViewControllerB = segue.destination as! TableViewControllerB
      tableViewControllerB.someData = sender as? Int
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
class TableViewControllerA: UITableViewController {
  var someData: Int?
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationItem.title = "Table 1"
  }
}
```

---

```
class TableViewControllerB: UITableViewController {
  var someData: Int?
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationItem.title = "Table 2"
  }
}
```

## Additional Info:

[image]

---

The way you do it is like below:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Dear Wilson , thank you so much for your response.

Could you please guide me , where do I have to paste your code in mine project?

please be specific as possible

Comment: stefan I provided you a basic example so you shouldn't paste my code to your project instead I suggest you to try to understand it, but the method you are interested for is `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: Dear Wilson. I am very pleased that you trying to help me to understand this stuff. However for now I really really really need a help on this.I learn best from the examples that I have . So please could you tell me how exactly and what part of the code I have to insert to mine code. I already created 2 classes (TableViewControllerA , TableViewControllerB as u suggested above and I inserted the codes. Thank you.I really hope that you will help

Comment: ok look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/wilsonbalderrama/2c2176dbac67f732b4f210877abf7151), you only need to add that code in `RestaurantTableViewController` view controller, make sure you created properly the segue in your storyboard, see these images ([image1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sTC9f.png), [image2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7qeoQ.png)) to make sure you did it right.

Comment: Thank you so much!
that really helped

Answer (score 0):

you can use UITableViewDelegate Methods like this

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            //open first view controller
            print("First row Click")
        case 1:
        //open Second view controller
            print("Second row Click")
        default:
             print("Nothing")
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, where do I paste it and where do I specify which controller must be opened ?

Comment: Where he says //open first view controller, you would just use     performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier", sender: self) to move to the relevant VC

Comment: in RestaurantTableViewController just bellow the cellForRowAt method you can above method and you can specify which controller must be opened at case 0: section and so on..

Comment: After case 0:    I wrote  performSegue(withIdentifier: "1", sender: self)

is that correct ?

Comment: yes , if you have set identifier as  "1" while creating Segue

Answer (score 0):

step 1: Connect all the segues from view controller and give segue Identifier to each connection.

see the how to connect and give ID : https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mq7G.jpg

step 2: write this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
import UIKit

class RestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var restaurantNames = ["Cafe Deadend", "Homei", "Teakha", "Cafe Loisl", "Petite Oyster", "For Kee Restaurant", "Po's Atelier", "Bourke Street Bakery", "Haigh's Chocolate", "Palomino Espresso", "Upstate", "Traif", "Graham Avenue Meats", "Waffle & Wolf", "Five Leaves", "Cafe Lore", "Confessional", "Barrafina", "Donostia", "Royal Oak", "Thai Cafe"]

var restaurantImages = ["cafedeadend.jpg", "homei.jpg", "teakha.jpg", "cafeloisl.jpg", "petiteoyster.jpg", "forkeerestaurant.jpg", "posatelier.jpg", "bourkestreetbakery.jpg", "haighschocolate.jpg", "palominoespresso.jpg", "upstate.jpg", "traif.jpg", "grahamavenuemeats.jpg", "wafflewolf.jpg", "fiveleaves.jpg", "cafelore.jpg", "confessional.jpg", "barrafina.jpg", "donostia.jpg", "royaloak.jpg", "thaicafe.jpg"]

var restaurantLocations = ["Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Sydney", "Sydney", "Sydney", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "London", "London", "London", "London"]

var restaurantTypes = ["Coffee & Tea Shop", "Cafe", "Tea House", "Austrian / Causual Drink", "French", "Bakery", "Bakery", "Chocolate", "Cafe", "American / Seafood", "American", "American", "Breakfast & Brunch", "Coffee & Tea", "Coffee & Tea", "Latin American", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "British", "Thai"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return restaurantNames.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RestaurantTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.nameLabel.text = restaurantNames[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImages[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
    cell.locationLabel.text = restaurantLocations[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.typeLabel.text = restaurantTypes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]


    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let segID1 = “first viewcontroller ID”
    let segID2 = “second viewcontroller ID”
    let segID3 = “third viewcontroller ID”
    let segID4 = “fourth viewcontroller ID”

    if indexPath.row == 0{
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segID1, sender: self)
    }else if indexPath.row == 1{
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segID2, sender: self)
    }else if indexPath.row == 2{
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segID3, sender: self)
    }else if indexPath.row == 3{
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segID4, sender: self)
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Identifiers write instead of  "segFirstTVC". It is just for example. So your identifier will write over there. For ex. let segID1 = “first viewcontroller ID”

Comment: Dear Ronak, Unofortunatley there is no didSelecrRowAtIndexPath Method

Comment: I have edited my answer try it. It not open some time because it is already inside class. Still missing the try comm+shift+k and retry.

Comment: Yeah, I def dont have didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Thank you very much for your new answer. Could you please exactly suggest to me where do I paste it? You have my code above.
Sorry for so many questions, I am very new

Comment: Wherever I paste it it says that override can only be specified on class members

Comment: remove the override word from that and try

Comment: Thank you! Still not working (( I dont know why

 It also asked me to change  if indexPath.row == 0{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segID1, sender: self)
        }else if indexPath.row == 1{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segID2, sender: self)
        }else if indexPath.row == 2{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segID3, sender: self)
        }else if indexPath.row == 3{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segID4, sender: self)

Maybe there is an issue in this?

Comment: I think it is issue of connection of segue or identifier. send me the proper error message.

Comment: So look, Do i need to connect segue from cell to a new controller or from  controller in which this cell to a new controller?

Comment: see the image for connection and give Identifier.
http://imgur.com/a/Ebm4V

Comment: Thats exactly how I did it and its still doesnt work

Are you sure that this solution is right ?
Basically wheneever I satart mine project works buy whenever I click the first cell or second or so on, nothing happens. So I dont have any crushes
Thank you

Comment: were is your email?